# Multiple inputs to IP core in verilog

Tags: verilog

I am trying to make communication system, with serialzing-deserialzing and 8b-10b encding, decoding. Currently I am using the readily available core for 8b/10b encoding, which has a 8 bit input requirement. I want to accept a 32 bit input from the user as a packet. And then feed the 8b/10b encoder with this 32 bits divided into 4, 8 bit patterns, serialize it and send it. How should I take the 32 bit pattern and divide it in 4, 8 bit patterns, when the IP core input demands only 8 bits?

Comment: Could you provide some more clarity? Are you asking how to split a 32b word into 4 bytes?

Comment: Yes. I wanted to know how to split and transmit the 32 bit word in 4 bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of details that you will need to figure out, but the basic way to do this is to have a state machine with 5 states: idle, transmit 1st, transmit 2nd, transmit 3rd, and transmit 4th.  When a 32 bit word comes in, you transition from Idle through the transmit states, writing one byte per clock cycle, then returning to idle or maybe begin transmitting the first byte of the next word if it is available.

The additional things you will have to figure out are whether you need flow control on the 32 bit input bus, how the receiver will determine the message start and end, whether a 32 bit message is a complete packet, or if you need to transmit longer packets generated 32 bits at a time.

8b10 makes most of these options fairly easy as it automatically figures out the byte framing and provides control code words that can be used for message framing, but you have to make sure it works for your application.

The code would look something like this:

```
reg [31:0] data_in;
reg [7:0] data_out;

always @(*) begin
    case (state) 
      Idle: data_out = 8'b0;
      Send1: data_out = data_in[31:24];
      Send2: data_out = data_in[23:16];
      Send3: data_out = data_in[15:8];
      Send4: data_out = data_in[7:0];
    endcase
end
```

You then have to make sure the state machine iterates through states Send1..Send4 at the appropriate time.  You may also have to latch the data_in register so it doesn't change in the middle of sending, and implement a busy flag so to prevent the sender from trying to send a new message while the first one is in progress.

Comment: Could you pls tell how I can divide the input which is 32 bits, into 4, 8 bit registers? The user will enter a 32 bit word(tx_in), which will be divided into 4, 8 bit registers(tx_in1,tx_in2,tx_in3,tx_in4)